# sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unterminated `s' command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to replace some texts of a file with another text. I tried following

```
#!/bin/bash

file="path/to/file.txt"
file_contents=$(cat "$file")
escaped_replacement="Some other text"
sed -i "s/$file_contents/$escaped_replacement/g" "$file"
```

It gives me error `sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unterminated` s' command`.

The file has the content

```
This
is
an
example
```

But when I change the text to `This is an example` it works perfectly okay.

It looks like when there is a newline in the text that I want to replace, it gives this error. How can I solve this?

I need to replace some texts with another text from some files.

Comment: what's the content of `$file_contents`? it likely contains `/`

Comment: sed processes the input line by line. You cannot match a multiline string like this even if the syntax was correct.

Comment: See [is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed) for why using sed for that (or any other approach using regexps instead of literal strings) will be a struggle. Consider using awk instead as it's also a mandatory POSIX tool, just like sed, but it can work with literal strings.

Comment: Are you actually trying to replace the entire contents of the file with `$escaped_replacement`? If so, don't use `sed`, just overwrite the file (deleting the old contents).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` processes the input line by line, so you can't match a multiline string.

You can use Perl which can read the whole file into memory (that's what the `-0777` does).

```
perl -0777 -pi -e "s/$file_contents/$escaped_replacement/g" "$file"
```

This can still break if the file contains a slash. You can prevent this by using an ENV variable instead of expanding the shell variable in the command before Perl sees it:

```
fc=$file_contents perl -0777 -pi -e "s/\$ENV{fc}/$escaped_replacement/g" "$file"
```

(and probably do the same with the other variable, then you can use single quotes for the expression, see below).

If the file contains special regex constructs (e.g. `{1,3}`) and you want to replace them literally, you might need to precede the pattern with a `\Q`. This will call [quotemeta](http://p3rl.org/quotemeta) to escape all the special characters for you.

```
fc=$file_contents er=$escaped_replacement perl -0777 -pi -e \
    's/\Q$ENV{fc}/$ENV{er}/g' "$file"
```

If you insist on using `sed`, here are some steps to try:

It seems you can prefix newlines with backslashes to prevent sed from complainig about syntax:

```
file_contents=${file_contents//$'\n'/$'\\\n'}
```

But you can't match a multiline string this way, even if the syntax was correct - unless you use GNU sed. It can load the whole file for you with `-z`, similarly to Perl above, so if you use the substitution mentioned above, you can run

```
sed -i -z "s=$file_contents=$escaped_replacement=" "$file"
```

You might also need to do more substitutions if the file contains slashes, backslashes, etc. For example,

```
file_contents=${file_contents//'\'/'\\'}  # Escape backslashes.
file_contents=${file_contents//'/'/'\/'}  # Escape slashes.
```

Comment: Might be better to show the best-practice perl approach (using environment variables) before the one that has caveats restricting its use.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Restructured, thanks.